# query in google datastore as $elemMatch in mongo

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to filter elements in array fulfilling all the criteria.

like if I have a array

> test: 
>   [{"organizationName":"strge","familyName":"raju"},{"organizationName":"sand","familyName":"sand"}]

I need query that filters all criteria in same element.I found that its done using $elemMatch in mongo but didnt find similar query in google datastore.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of an equality filter on an array value in Cloud Datastore as a `CONTAINS` filter.

So if you had an `GROUP` entity with a `members` property:

```
members: [
  { firstName: 'Alice', lastName: 'Smith' }
  { firstName: 'Bob'  , lastName: 'Miller' }
]
```

you could run:

```
SELECT * FROM Group WHERE
    members.firstName = 'Alice'
    AND members.lastName = 'Smith'
    AND members.firstName = 'Bob'
    AND members.lastName = 'Miller'
```

and it would return the above result.

However, this query doesn't check that the `firstName` and `lastName` values appear in the same `member` value. So this query would also return a `Group` entity that looks like:

```
members: [
  { firstName: 'Alice',  lastName: 'Jones' }
  { firstName: 'Bob'  ,  lastName: 'Jones' }
  { firstName: 'Chris',  lastName: 'Miller' }
  { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Smith' }
]
```

To prevent this, you would have to run the first query and then do client-side filtering.

Comment: you didnt get my question.If I use query SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE organizationName = 'strge' AND familyName = 'sand' it still provides me result whereas I want result only if organizationName = 'strge' AND familyName = 'raju' in this condition i.e both condition match in same object not different object

Comment: Ah, got it. I updated the answer -- let me know if it answers your question now.